# How to limit the memory used by PROMELA?

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, spin, promela

I am trying to limit the maximum memory used by PROMELA, by using the -DMEMLIMIT flag, like this.

```
./spin -a -DMEMLIMIT=1024 code.pml
```

But, still the memory keeps on increasing. Any idea, why is that so?

Comment: That `-DMEMLIMIT=1024` flag looks like it could be a compiler flag, not one you pass to the program. Do you have any documentation for this _spin_ program?

Comment: Actually SPIN produces C Code for model checking. That C Code contains that MEMLIMIT flag, the purpose of which is to limit the memory usage. But from what I am seeing, memory is not being limited.

Comment: I'm looking at the manual for _spin_ but there's no mention of a `-D` flag. Maybe you meant to compile the generated C file/s with the `-DMEMLIMIT=1024` flag?

Comment: http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/Roadmap.html. Actually its the same thing if you use the flag with spin or while compiling with gcc. I did both, and the result is the same.

Comment: The doc you linked to uses MEMLIM instead of MEMLIMIT.

Comment: That is the right :)! That was precisely the mistake I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

-DMEMLIM=N is a compiler flag passed to the gcc. It works that way:

./spin -a code.pml
gcc -DMEMLIM=1024 -o pan pan.c
./pan

You can also add further flags to enforce a better compression of states, like for instance -DCOLLAPSE which is a quite fast way to reduce the amount of memory needed.

Comment: Also thee `-w` option to `pan`: "-wN hashtable of 2^N entries (defaults to -w24)".